# Why does the PHP double arrow operator '=>' stop the execution of the code

Tags: php

I'm trying to create a web app and I want to make key value pair array. Like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8"></meta>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
  <title></title>
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="lib/jquery-1.11.0.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="script/main.js"></script>
</head>


<?php

$data = array('grant_type' => $authorization_code);

// more code goes here

?>

  <div class="container">

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

For some reason, the code above just prints *$authorization_code); // more code goes here ?>*

So it seems that the execution stops everytime I insert '=>' to the code. This occurs even if '=>' is commented.

Before down voting this please consider I already feel incredibly dumb and I really, really did not find an answer to this by Googling.

EDIT

Added full source.

Comment: put those two values in quotes

Comment: Neither the `=>` nor the literals will make PHP drop into unparsed HTML mode. If you want an answer, post your actual code; not some rehash. (Four cents on short open tags / not actually run as php script.)

Comment: It should work without a problem. However you get 2 notices because you don't put quotes for grant_type and authorization_code (I assume they are not defined using define)

Comment: Oh true, I should define but however, if I do, the results are the the same. Code exection stops to '=>

Comment: @JaakkoKarhu your edit changes the context completely, but you still haven't provided enough information. There is nothing that PHP would do that would cause your script to "print $authorization_code; // more code goes here ?>" - it's likely that you haven't got PHP set up correctly, so it's being treated as HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't quoted either of those values, so PHP is treating them as undefined [constants](http://php.net/manual/en/function.define.php).

Try

```
$data = array('grant_type' => $authorization_code);
```

or whatever it really should be instead.

```
php > $data = array(foo => bar);
PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant foo - assumed 'foo' in php shell code on line 1
PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant bar - assumed 'bar' in php shell code on line 1
php > define('foo', 'hello');
php > define('bar', 'world');
php > $data = array(foo => bar);
php > var_dump($data);
array(1) {
  ["hello"]=>
  string(5) "world"
}
```

As far as execution stopping goes, `=>` shouldn't be a PHP block sentinel value. only `?>` would "shut off" php.

Comment: Unfortunately the example above results *$authorization_code); // more code goes here ?>* And one below *$data = array(foo => bar); PHP Notice: Use of undefined constant foo - assumed 'foo' in php shell code on line 1 PHP Notice: Use of undefined constant bar - assumed 'bar' in php shell code on line 1 php > define('foo', 'hello'); php > define('bar', 'world'); php > $data = array(foo => bar); php > var_dump($data); array(1) { ["hello"]=> string(5) "world" } // more code goes here ?>*

Comment: You probably aren't running PHP code at all. Do a `view source`. You'll probably see ALL of your code, and `<?....=>` is being treated as an unknown/illegal HTML tag and simply being ignored by the browser.

Comment: Oh that's true. Didn't even cross my mind... it cuts the code to '>' that's the tag end... now I'm just wondering why isn't my php running at all, since my MAMP is definitely on... Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: Now I'm very confused. I changed the file extension to .php and it started working. Isn't php supposed to work inside html -file? Am I really this newbie?

Comment: php works anywhere that the PHP interpreter has been told it's present. If your webserver hasn't been told to pass .html files through the PHP plugin, then the php code will never ever get executed.